# Django REST Framework Delete Method Request receives Forbidden 403

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views, axios

**views.py**

```
class DeviceView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

serializer_class = DevicesSerializer
queryset = Devices.objects.all() 
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

**Axios Request**

```
    axios.delete(`api/devices/${data.id}/`, {}, {
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken }
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

When I carry out this request on my front-end, I get a response of :"DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/devices/4/ 403 (Forbidden)". Where 4 is the ID belonging to the record I would like to delete.

I am currently using Session Authentication in Django and I have passed in my CSRF Token value into the header of my request.

When I use other methods like PUT and POST on forms, they work fine. But, not DELETE

**What am I doing wrong to receive this error?**

Comment: Just to confirm you are getting this issue on Django development server?

Comment: A way to check the where is the issue is coming is using something like curl command on this delete url. If works its probably something with your ajax call, if not, is probably something with your api.

Comment: And Maybe a delete.CASCADE on the model could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to remove the empty body in the Axios request.

```
axios.delete(`api/devices/${data.id}/`, {
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken }
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```